# Angular 2 project's dependencies of a git submodule

Tags: angular, git, npm, git-submodules

I am developing an angular 8 project which contains a git submodule in src / app / submodule. I wish this submodule had a package.json of its own in which it recorded its dependencies. I would also like that by running an npm_install its dependencies were moved to the main node_modules of the project, in the root, in order to make them available to the whole application. Is it possible to achieve something similar with some solution? At the moment if I run npm install inside the folder I have as a consequence the creation of node_modules inside src / app / core, and I'm not happy with that because I have to be able to share its dependencies with the whole application. Tips?

Comment: Sounds like you want to create a library for your module. https://angular.io/guide/creating-libraries

Comment: Thanks but actually not, I just want my git submodule to have its own dependancies available to the whole application

Comment: Any updates? I also have this problem and can't find a solution